# IsEnabled binding broken when adding an EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism

I have this `TextBox` that is disabled when a `CheckBox` is ticked, using a binding on `IsEnabled`. This works fine on its own.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{MyValue}" IsEnabled="{Binding CheckBoxTicked}" />
```

```xml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckBoxTicked, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverterConverter}}"  />
```

I want to add a `LostFocus` event to this `TextBox` that will check if the value is correct using a command in the `ViewModel`.

```xml
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This works too, but the `IsEnabled` binding gets broken when the trigger is added and the `TextBox` no longer reacts to the ticking of the `CheckBox`.

Things I tried :

- If I force the `IsEnabled` to `False`, the `TextBox` is correctly disabled.
- If I change the name in the `InvokeCommandAction` binding to an incorrect command name, the binding to the `CheckBox` works again.

Comment: What does `LostFocusCommand` do?

Comment: Not much at the moment, it hides or show another TextBlock, just so I can be sure it is called.

Comment: What if you remove the converter or replace `prism:InvokeCommandAction` with `i:InvokeCommandAction`?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, it works, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex Which one did the trick, removing the converter or changing the `InvokeActionCommand`?

Comment: @thatguy Changing the namespace of ``InvokeCommandAction``, so the namespace is now ``xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove the converter or replace `<prism:InvokeCommandAction ... />` with `<i:InvokeCommandAction ... />`. Then it should work.